# Jasmine testing setting component variable

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm using spyOn, in a jasmine test, to "listen" to a function call from a service,

that function returns an Observable.

I'm getting the error unexpected token U JSON;

The error is generated from the component line:

```
this.config = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('configuration'));
```

The localStorage item was JSON.stringified;

I understand that this error is usually thrown when JSON.parse = undefined,

So I tried to set the variable within my test i.e.

```
component.config =  mockConfig;
```

So..

```
 // Storage Mock
  function storageMock() {
    var storage = {};
      return {
      setItem: function(key, value) {
        storage[key] = value || '';
      },
      getItem: function(key) {
        return key in storage ? storage[key] : null;
      },
      removeItem: function(key) {
        delete storage[key];
      },
      get length() {
        return Object.keys(storage).length;
      },
      key: function(i) {
        var keys = Object.keys(storage);
        return keys[i] || null;
      }
    };
  }
  let mockConfig = JSON.stringify({
    base_url:"http://image_url/",
    poster_sizes:['w9', 'w100']
  })
  //Set storage
 let m =  storageMock()
 m.setItem('configuration', mockConfig)

  it('Should set items array with values from MoviesService', () => {
    component.config = JSON.parse(m.getItem('configuration'));
       let spy = spyOn(moviesService, 'getPreview').and.callFake(()=>{
        return Observable.from([[{id1: 1, title: 'a'}, {id1: 2, title: 'b'}]])
  })
  component.ngAfterViewInit();
  expect(component.items.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
});
```

Comment: you need to mock localStorage.getItem in unit testing because localStorage is not available there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Julia, I've updated my code with a mock localStorage function, however the problem still persists, with the same message, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: it is hard to say without seeing at the component code but I would try to add async to your test since you are dealing with observables. like  it('balala', async(() => {..}));

Comment: Thanks Julia, I got it working and added an answer, but if you want to add your comment as an answer, I can mark it as correct, Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who come across this problem I got this working by  by placing this code in the beforeEach wrapper

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: m });
```

Basically it uses my mock localStorage variable instead of the one from the window object.